# Pjsua Sound distortion

Tags: c, pjsua2

I have transplanted the compiled PJSUA to nuc980 platform and compiled one on Windows platform. The connection is normal, but the transmitted audio is distorted. The sound from Nuc980 is very thick, while that from Windows is very thin.  The configuration files are the same as the following

```
--log-level 0
--app-log-level 0
--local-port 5060
--srtp-secure 0
--srtp-keying 0
#--snd-auto-close 1
--clock-rate 32000
--snd-clock-rate 32000
--quality 2
--ec-tail 10
--ec-opt 2
--rtp-port 4000
--dis-codec ilbc
--dis-codec GSM
--dis-codec L16
--dis-codec G722
--add-codec speex
--no-tcp
--auto-answer 200
--max-calls 4
--use-compact-form
#--use-timer 1
--thread-cnt 4
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the source code as a [mre].

Comment: The list of disabled codecs is not that useful. Which code _is_ used for the connection? Next up, figure out what limit you're htting. CPU? Network bandwidth?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.